# Larger than NamedSize.Large text

Tags: xamarin.forms

How could we extend the NamedSize to get a larger text?

The below LOC gives out a large size but I would like to have a larger one and yet not hardcoded:

```
myLabel.TextSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.NamedSize/

> MEMBER NAME    DESCRIPTION
>
> Default    The default font size.
>
> Large  A Large font size, for titles or other important text elements.
>
> Medium A default font size, to be used in stand alone labels or buttons.
>
> Micro  The smallest readable font size for the device. Think about this like legal footnotes.
>
> Small  A small but readable font size. Use this for block of text.

A larger font size does not exist in the NamedSize Enumeration. You could create a custom property MyFontSize and set it to a different value, based on the current device and have your label's size bound to that property.

It's still hard-coded, but you'd have to play around with size values to make it look the way you want on each device.